# Why am I getting status 10000 from Gimbal registering the api key?

Tags: ios, gimbal, beacon, qualcomm

I am integrating the Gimbal SDK following their documentation. I have the framework, requisite lib, bridge-header, import of framework.  I discovered some problems with the bundle and api-key when using spaces or dashes in the names, so I have simplified the project name.

I created the project with bundle name (i.e., %PRODUCT_NAME) of POCGimbalNoPunctuationBundleId and the bundle ID prefix is com.mycompany.ios

I then created the API key in Gimbal Manager using the product name, bundle ID prefix that generated a key that I copied into my appdelegate code.

The set-apikey is invoked and the SDK logs:

```
2015-08-25 19:14:32:078 POCGimbalNoPunctuationBundleId[17282:607] Request (v10/registration/) failed: Error Domain=QLRestTemplateErrorDomain Code=-1011 "Expected status code in (200-299), got 400" UserInfo=0x7feeb151bad0 {NSLocalizedDescription=Expected status code in (200-299), got 400, QL_HTTP_STATUS_CODE=400, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://ios.api.gimbal.com/service/v10/registration/, NSLocalizedFailureReason={"errorMessage":"Application verification failed. Invalid com.mycompany.ios.POCGimbalNoPunctuationBundleId for application with package com.mycompany.ios.POCGimbalNoPunctuationBundleId","statusCode":10000}}
2015-08-25 19:14:32:079 POCGimbalNoPunctuationBundleId[17282:607] Error during registration:Expected status code in (200-299), got 400
```

I understand WHAT it is telling me, but I don't understand WHY -- it all appears to match the sample app and the API key in the Gimbal manager.

HELP!  I have struggled with this off and on for three days now.

Answer (score 0):

It was not clear in the documentation (to me) that the bundle ID was to include the product name.  I thought that as built internally.  Therefore, the correct answer was to append "MyAppName" to the bundle ID in the question.

```
com.mycompany.ios.MyAppName
```

Be careful the product names that include spaces or dashes.  They are converted to underbar (_).  Good luck.